# Selecting first element from the dropdown [ select tag ] cause the backend to crash but selecting other works just fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I'm building a simple app with node.js and reactjs but the problem arises when I want to add book especially while selecting dropdown value.
In the **select** tag when I select the first element it crashes the backend but when I select the second or below it they work just fine. What could be the reason behind it ? Dropdown menu has been filled correctly. My code is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

 export default class AddBook extends Component {

  state = {
        name : '',
        author : '',
        publishers : '',
        pages :'',
        genres : [],
        genre : '',
        addedMessage : null
   }

  async componentDidMount() {
     const genres = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/genres')
      this.setState({ genres : genres.data})
   }

  onInputChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value }) //looks for name
}

onFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    const book = {
      name : this.state.name,
      author : this.state.author,
      publishers : this.state.publishers,
      pages : this.state.pages,
      genres : this.state.genre
    }

axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/books', book)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log("error occured while posting data ", err)) 
console.log(book)
//alert("book added successfully !!!")
this.setState({addedMessage : 'Book added successfully'})
window.location = "/books"
}

render() {
  const { name, author, publishers, pages, genres, addedMessage } = this.state;
    return (
    <div className="container">
        <h2>ADD BOOK </h2>
    { addedMessage && <h2 style={{textAlign : 'center'}} className="alert alert-info">{addedMessage}</h2> }

        <form onSubmit = { this.onFormSubmit }>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name">BookName:</label>
              <input type="text" required className="form-control" id="name" 
              placeholder="Enter Book name" name="name" 
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
              value={name}
              />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="author">Author:</label>
              <input type="text" required={ true } className="form-control" 
              id="author" placeholder="Enter Author" name="author" 
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
              value={author}
              />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="publishers">Publishers:</label>
              <input type="text" required className="form-control" 
              id="publishers" placeholder="Enter Publishers Name"
              name="publishers" 
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
              value={publishers}
              />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="pages">Pages:</label>
            <input type="number" required className="form-control"
             id="pages" placeholder="Enter No of Page" name="pages" 
             onChange={this.onInputChange}
             value={pages}
             />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="genre">Category:</label>
            <select type="select" className="form-control" 
            id="genre" 
            name="genre"
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
            > 
        {/* <option value="selectCategory" onChange={this.onInputChange}>Select</option> */}
              { 
                  genres.map( genre => (
                    <option key={genre._id}  onChange={this.onInputChange} value={genre.name}> 
                     {genre.name }</option> 
                  ))
              }
            </select>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>  
       )
    }
 }
```

My backend is up and running and has successfully fetched the genres[ categories ] , but I am not able
to figure out why selecting the first doesn't work but others just work fine. How should I solve it ?

It shows the following error for this case.

```
 Error: Book validation failed: genres: Path `genres` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect 
    (E:\nodejs\nodejs\MERN_STACK_Book\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:48:26)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:718:31)     
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:287:10)
    at afterInspector (internal/errors.js:682:14) {      
    errors: {
    genres: ValidatorError: Path `genres` is required.   
        at validate (E:\nodejs\nodejs\MERN_STACK_Book\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1178:13)
        at E:\nodejs\nodejs\MERN_STACK_Book\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1161:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate 
    (E:\nodejs\nodejs\MERN_STACK_Book\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1106:14)
        at E:\nodejs\nodejs\MERN_STACK_Book\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2387:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'genres',
      value: '',
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
     }
   },
    _message: 'Book validation failed'
   }
   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

And code for my book schema is as follows

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
//schema for genres

const bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
          type : String,
          required : true,
          trim : true,
          unique : true //title is made unique.
    },
    author : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        trim : true

    },
    publishers : {
        type : String,
        trim : true,

    },

    pages : {
        type : Number,
        required : true,
        trim : true

    },
    genres : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        trim : true

    },

    create_date : {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now
    }
})

//It will create books collection in your database and documents 
//inside that collection will have fields from bookSchema when you save first document.
const Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)

//get the books
module.exports.getBooks = (callback, limit) => {
    //  Book.find(callback)
    Book.find(callback).limit(limit)
}

//get single book
module.exports.getBookById = (id,callback) => {
    //  Book.find(callback)
    Book.findById(id,callback);
}

module.exports.addBook = (book,callback) => {
    Book.create(book, callback);
}

module.exports.updateBook = (id,book,options, callback) => {
    
    const query = {
        _id : id
    }
    const updatedBook = {
        name : book.name,
        author : book.author,
        publishers : book.publishers,
        pages : book.pages,
        genres : book.genres
    } 
    Book.findByIdAndUpdate(query, updatedBook, {} , callback);
}

module.exports.deleteBook = (id,callback) => {
    const query = {
        _id : id
    }
    Book.findByIdAndDelete(query, callback);
}
```

I checked some of the similar answers in the stackoverflow but couldn't figure out why I'm getting that
error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem with your code :

1. The first option of the dropdown is chosen by default, and thus "selecting" the first option doesn't trigger the Category dropdown's `onChange` function (because the selected value doesn't really change).
2. Since the default value of `this.state.genre` is an empty string, the `genres` property of the book you send to the backend also has `genres` as an empty string.
3. Finally, Mongoose does not accept an empty string for a `required` string field, which gives you the `Path 'genres' is required` error.

Try switching to another option and back to the first. It will work then because the `onChange` function will then get called and `this.state.genre` will be set properly.

There are a few ways to fix this:

- Add a placeholder option to the dropdown - something like "Select an option...". Then the user will be forced to select a genre from the dropdown and `onChange` would be called.
- Or, in `componentDidMount`, set `this.state.genre` to the first genre of the list of genres you fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . That didn't work and I got another type of error related to my backend , I think I need to fix something  in my backend .

Comment: No problem, please let me know if you get it working!

Comment: It works, problem was in backend part. I inspected and found It was failing with validation type in my mongoose Schema.